# MYSQL PHP Select Order By

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have example table date_table, as a basis of data filter
2 columns - day and day_of_week
I do query in SQL

```
select distinct day_of_week,day  from date_table
order by day_of_week
```

No problem

```
day_of_week        day
1                  Monday
2                  Tuesday
3                  Wednesday
4                  Thursday
5                  Friday
6                  Saturday
7                  Sunday
```

Then I implement this into select box in PHP , so I can choose value

```
$query = "
select distinct day_of_week,day  from date_table
order by day_of_week
";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
$option = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
if(!empty($_REQUEST["sday"]))
   {
  if($row['day_of_week'] == $_REQUEST["sday"])
    $option .= '<option  value = "'.$row['day_of_week'].'"

    selected="selected">'.$row['day'].'</option>';
   else
   $option .= '<option  value =
    "'.$row['day_of_week'].'">'.$row['day'].'</option>';        
}
  else
 $option .= '<option  value = "'.$row['day_of_week'].'">'.$row['day'].'</option>';  
}
```

And Select Box

```
<select name="sday" class="sday">
<option value="">Select Day</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
```

- Problem 1

the end Result is something Like

```
Monday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Thursday
Tuesday
Wednesday
```

- Problem 2

When I select Value "Monday" , all fine . It passes value "1"

When I select "Tuesday", It selects value 2,3 and 7. Same with wednesday and sunday.

There are few other select boxes, that are made with same idea, works fine.
There are no data duplicates.

What could be the problem?

Comment: is there a typo in second last line `$option5 .=`?

Comment: $query = "select day_of_week, day from date_table order by day_of_week"; and also re-write $option instead of $option5.

Comment: Why are you using MySQL at all for this!?!?

Comment: What values are in `$_REQUEST["sday"]`?

Comment: @Strawberry some Calendar systems store days in the database.

Comment: @Shamil - this code is used to build a dropdown box. It stores nothing (although a calendar system that stores days sounds silly to me)

Comment: @Strawberry Ideally, it would be outside - and I agree that it sounds silly, but it allows for greater flexibility if for some reason we want to rename a day etc. Moreover, it could be used elsewhere.

Comment: @Shamil Rename a day? Why would you want to rename a day? Either way, this code still stores nothing!

Comment: try `ORDER BY day_of_week ASC` as suggested by @Shamil. The code is fine. I'd made a [snippet](http://ideone.com/LKlTTc), but its not using database.

Comment: The problem is that , If i choose Wed, Tue,or Sunday it gives me sday=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to

```
 ORDER BY day_of_week ASC
```

You may want to restructure your code a but such that

```
$selectedString = ($row['day_of_week'] == $_REQUEST["sday"]) ? ' selected ' : '';

<option value = "<?php echo $row['day_of_week'];?>" <?php echo $selectedStr;?> ><?php echo $row['day'];?></option>'
```

Comment: +1 for `($row['day_of_week'] == $_REQUEST["sday"]) ? ' selected ' : '';`

Comment: Problem is in "sday". If I choose Sunday, It gives value 2 or 3 or 7

Comment: @kaulainais can you `GROUP BY day_of_week`? There's no reason why all three of them should be selected, unless your input is incorrect.

Comment: I think I know whee the problem is. Thanks Shamil

Answer (score 0):

you use variable `$option5`, instead of `$option`

Comment: I changed it. that is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    if(!empty($_REQUEST["sday"]))
{
    if($row['day_of_week'] == $_REQUEST["sday"])
    {
        $option .= '<option  value = "'.$row['day_of_week'].'"
        selected="selected">'.$row['day'].'</option>';
    }
    else
    {
        $option .= '<option  value ="'.$row['day_of_week'].'">'.$row['day'].'</option>';
    }
}
else
{
$option .= '<option  value = "'.$row['day_of_week'].'">'.$row['day'].'</option>';
```

}

Its cleaner and you will dont have problems with bracktes

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Why not do this instead (the array isn't even necessary, but hey)...

```
<select>
<?php
$days = array('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday');

for($i=0;$i<count($days);$i++){

echo "<option>$days[$i]</option>\n";

}

?>

</select>
```